# UITabbarController - how to deselect all tabs in iOS 5.0 and iOS 4.3 as well

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I tried using the following snippet

```
DefaultView *defaultView = [[DefaultView alloc]initWithNibName:@"DefaultView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:nil];
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:defaultView];
```

It works for iOS 4.3 and below but on iOS 5.0 it gives the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected.'
```

Any clues as to what should be done in iOS 5.0 to get around this error?

Comment: is there no way this can be done?

Answer (score -1):

DefaultView is one of your tabs? If yes try this to select it:

```
NSUInteger newIndex = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:defaultView];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:newIndex];
```

I don't know if it's what you expected, maybe more informations?

*Edit : You got this error because : `only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected`. That means default view isn't in your list of view so you can't select it.*

Comment: When you down vote, at least take time to explain why. There is no answer on this post, I've tried to help that's all.